# Bounds checking when calling computed property's setter using -=/+=

Tags: swift, computed-properties

I am trying to make sure a computed property's setter only sets `newValue` within a certain range. The computed property's backing value is a `UInt`.

So what I thought I could do is use `min(max(newValue, 0), UInt.max)`, like so:

```
private var _value: UInt = 100

public var value: UInt {
    get { return _value }
    set { _value = min(max(newValue, 0), UInt.max) }
}
```

But when I use a for loop to decrement the value using `-=` I throw an exception.

```
for _ in 0..<1000 {
   value -= 1
}
```

It seems this doesn't do any bounds checking. Is there a way around this?

It must be a computed property so I can't use didSet. The property is actually an alias for a value in an array of other values. The above is merely for example's sake.

Comment: You're subtracting 1 from a 0 Uint. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `value -= 1` is equivalent to `value = value - 1`. As you can see, `value - 1` has to be calculated before `value` can be set, so your bounds checking code never even has a chance to run. Even if it did run, it would never find a value less than 0 to bounds-check, as your property is a `UInt`.

If you change your property to `Int`, this will work as intended, and there is even some precedent in Cocoa for using `Int` even in cases when negative numbers make no sense. (It will still be pointless to check against `Int.max`, however, for the same reason.)